# Sharepoint online List and item level permission using pnpPowershel

Tags: sharepoint, powershell-4.0

I am trying to pull Site/List/Library/Item/subsite level permissions/unique permission on our SharePoint online site using the script below from reference :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/77a8e9ef-56a5-47e4-9b54-209f37687013/sharepoint-online-subsite-permissions-list-credenstials-promt?forum=onlineservicessharepoint - Marked as answer by MichaelIT02

However, I am getting site/subsites level permission only in PNP Powershell using above code. I tried to work on scripts in PNP to get list and library permission/unique permission but unable to find an idea. If anyone could help me to extend same code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!!

Please check below code:
Here in I am unable to get Item level permission.

```
$siteUrl="https://TestSite.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamsiteSample"
$outputFile= "C:\Users\123\Desktop\SiteAndSubsitePermission.csv" 
$username="xyz@xyz.onmicrosoft.com"
$password="xyz@12345"
$encpassword = convertto-securestring -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - 
argumentlist $username, $encpassword

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credentials $credential

# output file name and location
"List Title `t Title `t PrincipalType `t Permission `t GivenThrough" | Out-File 
$outputFile -Append

#`t LoginName
# get document library
$library = Get-PnpList -Includes RoleAssignments
#-Identity $libraryName -Includes RoleAssignments

foreach($libraryList in $library)
{

# get all the users and groups who has access
$roleAssignment = $libraryList.RoleAssignments
foreach ($roleAssignment in $roleAssignment)
{
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $roleAssignment -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, 
Member

$ListTitle = $libraryList.title
$loginName = $roleAssignment.Member.LoginName
$title = $roleAssignment.Member.Title
$principalType = $roleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType
$givenThrough = ""
$permissionLevel = ""

# loop through permission levels assigned to specific user/group
foreach ($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings){
    $PermissionLevel += $RoleDefinition.Name + ";"
}
$givenThrough = "Given directly"
"$($ListTitle) `t $($title)  `t $($principalType) `t $($permissionLevel) `t 
$($givenThrough)" | Out-File $outputFile -Append

#`t $($loginName)

# if principal is SharePoint group -> get SharePoint group members
#if ($roleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType.ToString() -eq "SharePointGroup")
#  {
#    $givenThrough = $roleAssignment.Member.Title.ToString()

#    $groupMembers = Get-PnpGroupMembers -Identity $roleAssignment.Member.LoginName
 #   foreach ($member in $groupMembers)
#    {
#        "$($member.Title) `t $($member.LoginName) `t $($member.PrincipalType) `t 
 $($permissionLevel) `t $($title) `t $($ListTitle)" | Out-File $outputFile -Append
#    }
 # }
 }
 }


$subwebs=Get-PNPSubWebs 
foreach($subweb in $subwebs) 
{ 
#Connect-PNPonline -Url $siteUrl -Credentials $credential
#Write-Host $subweb.Url 
$groups=Get-PNPGroup 
foreach($group in $groups) 
{ 
#$DLGP = "" | Select "SiteUrl","GroupName","Permission" 

$sPerm=Get-PNPGroupPermissions -Identity $group.loginname -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue |Where-Object {$_.Hidden -like "False"} 
if ($sPerm -ne $null) 
{ 
$SiteUrl=$subwebs.title 
$GroupName=$group.loginname 
$Permission=$sPerm.Name 
#Test columns
"$($SiteUrl) `t $($GroupName)  `t $($Permission)" | Out-File $outputFile -Append
} 
} 
Write-Host $subweb.Url "permission fetched!" }
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I have edited my question. Kindly check my understanding.